# Add digital certificate authentication without paying any royalty?

Tags: windows, authentication, digital-certificate

My application is closed source but free to use for all purposes.
Whenever it is launched for the first time on any PC, [this](http://www.thawte.com/assets/products/images/Office2007_VBA_SelfSigned.jpg) warning is showed for my application.
I do not like it and want to solve this problem and I feel there are 2 possible solutions:

- **Add a digital certificate authentication:**
  Pay huge money to Verisign and get the certificate.
  But since I am not earning any money from the application itself, I cannot pump my own money just to satisfy Windows.
  Also I cannot use the free certificates as they are allowed only for open source applications and I do not plan to open source my application.
- **Disable the warning message:**
  Somehow make Windows to not show this warning.

Any ideas how I can get past my problem?

Comment: Consider making your application [free software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software). It then is more likely to become trusted in the long run.

Comment: Let's turn this around... you don't want anyone to be able to look at your program to convince themselves it's not malware, and you don't want to pay someone to say they've seen your ID so that your reputation's at stake, and you don't want users warned that they're effectively being asked to run some anonymous opaque untrusted software?  What's do you think the point of the whole strong signing system is, if it can't let users differentiate such software?

Comment: Is it not possible to determine whether it is a malware or not by scanning from the executable code? Why do you need the source code for that? Also why do you have to pay periodically to maintain the certificate?

Comment: @Cool_Coder: Such scanning is possible, that's what virus scanners do. And apparently your program does not trigger AV warnings, so that bit is covered. But a certificate doesn't say anything about content, it says something about th author (you).

Comment: @MSalters ok I understood the requirement of the digital CA. So now either I have to make my application open source or pay huge royalty. These are my only options?

Comment: Or get an existing certificate owner to sign on your behalf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you creating an application or a VBA script? For applications code signing is not required - you are not obliged to sign the resulting XE and DLLs. If you don't do this, no warnings are shown.

And if you want the certificate authority to issue the certificate for you, you pay them for the service of checking your identity, confirming it and convincing others to trust their (CA's) certificate issued to you.

There seemed to be some CA issuing free code signing certificates but personally I would not trust such service, cause the service costs money and when it's given for free, there's something suspicious there.

Comment: I am creating an application which consists of an exe and some dll's. Yes code signing is not obligatory, but there is a warning shown by Windows which sort of creates a sense of fear that it is a virus in a "non-power" user. AFAIK the free signing is done for open source applications only.

Comment: As a side note I cannot any certificate for VLC media player, but Windows does not warn us, why? Similarly for Notepad++, but for Everything.exe it does show the warning every time the exe is launched.

Comment: @Cool_Coder I don't know what exactly warning is shown. Maybe that depends on system policy settings of some kind. On some average computer nothing is shown for unsigned user-mode EXE.